# Trying to create a class having 2 objects as a variable in c++. Linking and non-static error

Tags: c++, linker, non-static

I've pasted the code below and errors too. Please check why I'm getting this error. I'm trying to make a class and pass 2 object as a parameter.

I want to deﬁne a class named Customer that has two member data elements: a name and an address. This involves creating customer.cpp and customer.h. The class should offers a get member function for each member data element.

Getting this error. 
cpp|64|error: no matching function for call to 'customer::customer()'

if I use customer c() instead of customer c = new customer(); - I got this error
cpp|65|error: request for member 'ob' in 'c', which is of non-class type 'customer()'|

Customer.h file

```
#ifndef CUST_H
#define CUST_H
#include "name.h"
#include "address.h"

class customer
{
public:
name ob;
address ob1;

customer(name &,address &);
name getname();
address getaddress();

};

#endif
```

Customer.cpp file

```
// in customer.cpp
#include "customer.h"



customer::customer(){
    ob = new name();
    ob1 = new address();
                        }

customer(name &x,address &y){
                        ob=x;
                        ob1=y;
                        }

name getname()
{
     return ob;
}

address customer::getaddress()
{
     return ob1;
}
```

main.cpp file

```
int main() {
name a = readRestOfName(in, given); // returning object of name in a
address b=readAddress(in); // returning object of address in b

//pass a,b into customer class object constructor
customer c = new customer();
c.ob = a;
c.ob1 = b;
}
```

Comment: since you have defined constructor - customer(name &,address &) , the compiler will not create a default constructor for you (i,e customer() ) . you have to define the default constructor yourself. I recommend this http://www.ycshao.com/?p=308

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your default constructor declaration in your .h file.
    customer();